# Identify OK button in Dialog.action_area

Tags: gtk, widget, pygtk

I create a Dialog, and at some point I need to toggle sensitive flag of OK button (gtk.STOCK_OK). I successfully access action_area and buttons in it, but how do I identify the OK button?
Also, is there a simpler way to enable/disable OK button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the label should work, but it's very fragile; translations will probably break it, and your positive-response buttons won't always be called "OK" anyway. You should consider using the response ID to identify the appropriate button instead. For example, a typical OK button might be created using:

```
dialog.add_button(gtk.STOCK_OK, gtk.RESPONSE_OK)
```

You can then retrieve your OK button later using the `get_widget_for_response` call, which seems perfectly designed to do exactly what you want to do:

```
dialog.get_widget_for_response(gtk.RESPONSE_OK)
```

I'd suggest that this is probably the way you *should* do it; it's similar to the way that the `set_alternative_button_order()` API works, which suggests that it's what was intended.

Answer (score 1):

must be something like that :

```
for child in action_area.get_children():
    label = child.get_children()[0]
    if label.get_label() == "OK":
        child.set_sensitive(False)
```

Comment: I think, child.get_label() will do the task.
if child.get_label() == 'gtk-ok':
    child.set_sensitive(False)